# What is updateQuery supposed to do in a client subscription - props are not updating

Tags: react-apollo, apollo-client

Using an apollo client with a graphql subscription, I'm following along in the example but I don't see the updateQuery from the subscription event updating my properties.  Does the return value from the updateQuery supposed to be handled automatically - or am I supposed to persist it to the store myself?

```
 componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
  if (!newProps.data.loading && !this.subscription) {

    this.subscription = newProps.data.subscribeToMore({
      document: getMessages,
      variables: { id: 'foo'},
      updateQuery: (previousState, {subscriptionData}) => {
        const newEntry = subscriptionData.data.createMessage;
        return {
          Conversation: {
            messages: [
              ...previousState.Conversation.messages,
              {
                ...newEntry
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      onError: (err) => console.error(err),
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: There have been problems with `updateQuery` and queries whose components are currently not mounted. In that case it might be better to use [reducer](http://dev.apollodata.com/react/cache-updates.html#resultReducers). Also, can you add the query that you refer to with `Conversation`? You have to be careful with naming, otherwise Apollo doesn't know which query to update.

Comment: the query would be something like ` query getMessages($foo: ID!) {
    Post(id:$foo) {
      id
      messages(orderBy: createdAt_DESC) {
        id
        message
        user {
          id
          username
          thumbnail
        }
        createdAt
      }
    }
  }`

Comment: Then instead of `Conversation` you have to say `getMessages` and instead of `messages` you have to say `Post` that returns the new messages object. Compare with the `Comment` query and `updateQueries` example [here](http://dev.apollodata.com/react/cache-updates.html#updateQueries)

Comment: sorry the comment was wrong - I renamed some things for the example, it would have been `...Conversation: { messages ...` in the the return object... in debugging the newEntry and the return object look to be good

Comment: subscription createMessage($foo: ID!) {
            createMessage(filter:{ conversation: { id: $foo } }) {
              id
              message
              user {
                id
                username
                thumbnail
              }
              createdAt
            }
          }